# Omitting 'new' keyword causing unexplainable problems in javascript constructor function

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I am a newbie in javascript, and was studying about constructor functions and the `new` keyword. After omitting `new` intentionally, it is causing some problems, and I am not able to understand exactly why is it happening.

```
let Fruit = function (person, color) {
    this.person = person;
    this.color = color;
    this.displayInfo = function () {
        console.log(this.person + " is " + this.color);
    }
}
let altFruit = function (person, color) {
    this.person = person;
    this.color = color;
}

let a1 = altFruit('Banana', 'Yellow');   //new keyword not written
let f1 = new Fruit('Orange', 'orange');

let aFunction = f1.displayInfo;
aFunction();
```

I didn't write `new` when initialising object `a1`. I stored the function `f1.displayinfo` in a variable, and then called it. Expected output was `undefined is undefined`, but instead I got `Banana is Yellow`.

It is really baffling to me because `aFunction` has nothing to do with `altFruit` constructor function or `a1`. Also, even after seeing many tutorials, I still don't really understand what is the exact meaning of `new` because this weird output is happening only when I omit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value of `this` depends on *how* the function is called.

In non-strict mode, when you call the `altFruit` function without the `new` keyword, `this` inside it will refer to the global `window` object. So,

```
this.person = person;
```

will add `person` property on the global `window` object. (you can test this by logging `window.person` on the console at the end of your code).

When you call `aFunction`, in non-strict mode, value of `this` inside `displayInfo` function will refer to the global `window` object.

In short, your code is adding and reading properties to and from the global `window` object, respectively.

#### The "new" operator

`new` operator is used to create instances of user-defined object types (like `Fruit`) or built-in object types (like `Array`, `Date`, etc).

When you call `new Fruit(...)`, `new` operator will do the following things:

1. Create a new object
2. Add `__proto__` property on the newly created object that points to `Fruit.prototype` object.
3. Point `this` inside the `Fruit` constructor to the newly created object.
4. Return the newly created object from the `Fruit` constructor function.

For more details, see: [`MDN: new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)